# Neo4j apoc.periodic.repeat doesn't work with streams.publish

Tags: neo4j, apache-kafka, neo4j-apoc

Does anyone ever used Neo4j apoc.periodic.repeat function to publish message to kafka?
Here is what I have now:

I have a working query to send message to my kafka topic:

```
CALL streams.publish("my-neo4j-topic", "Hello World from Neo4j!")
```

However, when I used apoc repeat function:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.repeat('kafka-only',
    'CALL streams.publish("my-neo4j-topic", "Hello World from Neo4j!")', 
5)
```

Nothing happens..

I have checked the log/debug log and can't get any hint. Can anyone help me?

This is my configuration:

```
# Add this for Streams Config
kafka.zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
streams.procedures.enabled=true
streams.source.enabled=true
streams.source.schema.polling.interval=10000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it is a bug...

https://community.neo4j.com/t/neo4j-apoc-periodic-repeat-doesnt-work-with-streams-publish/12313/9

And the neo4j will have a fix in the next release.